# How to get/set data for each programmatically generated fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dynamically-generated

I have question about programmatically generated fragments in the android.
Now I'm creating  app that helps in training on the gym. I want to create something like "live training" - that means user will have some exercises, each exercise will have weight to lift etc. 
I was thinking that each exercise would be a fragment (and have own data), but now I think about how to communicate to autogenerated fragments from parent activity to e.g read some data.
The user should be able to switch between exercises (so any series and weight should be saved for each exercise 
until the workout is finished), but now i'm looking for best solution for that and I'm stuck :/. I've never done such a thing before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Model View View Model Architecture with live data for observing data changes.**

Architecture Components provides ViewModel helper class for the UI controller that is responsible for preparing data for the UI. ViewModel objects are automatically retained during configuration changes so that data they hold is immediately available to the next activity or fragment instance.

**View Model**

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

**Master Fragment**

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}
```

**Details Fragment**

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, item -> {
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

For further information explore the android developer documentation for MVVM Architecture

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel